# Need to get affected rows from powershell

Tags: powershell

I execute multiple SQL scripts against multiple databases using PowerShell. I need to get messages tab content(affected rows) into out file but could not find solution to this problem. 
I have tried the following:

```
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '*******' -Database $databaseName -Query $scriptContent -username "*****" -password "*********" -Verbose 4> $messages
```

where messages is the log file but after the scripts execution, the file is empty

Comment: I have read in multiple articles that -verbose must do what i need but my case it doesn't

Comment: Welcome to SO. Update your question to meet the standard of [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try using [`sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) directly rather than `Invoke-SqlCmd`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the outputs of a `select statement` in tabular format try below

```
write-host ($result | Format-List | Out-String)
```

If you want the affected records count, add below immediately after your query

```
Select @@ROWCOUNT
```

so your query & poweshell will be

```
$scriptContent = "DELETE FROM YourTable; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS DeletedRows"
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance '*******' -Database $databaseName -Query $scriptContent -username "*****" -password "*********" -Verbose 4> $messages
Write-Host "Total rows deleted: $($Results.DeletedRows)"
```